# Reabriendo la pregunta: ¿Por qué en caso de empate el programa no finaliza?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta, motivos-de-cierre

En mi modesta opinión, [dicha pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78459/19610) se cerró incorrectamente:

- ¿La pregunta se entiende? -Sí. Fallo o error en caso de consumir todos los movimientos y ningún jugador sea ganador. Las palabras exactas son:

  > ¿Por qué en caso de empate el programa no finaliza?
- ¿Tiene un *ejemplo mínimo y verificable*? -Sí. Feo y sin comentarios, pero lo tiene. Y tengo la *ligera* sospecha de que el OP no es capaz de *minificarlo* más.
- ¿Se indica el comportamiento observado? -Sí, en el propio título de la pregunta: En el caso de fin de los movimientos y ningún ganador, el programa no finaliza su ejecución.
- ¿Se indica el comportamiento esperado? -También. En el propio título. En caso de fin de los movimientos y ningún ganador, el programa debería de finalizar.

Por todo lo anterior, creo que el cierre fue *incorrecto*, y que debería de reabrirse.

Y, anecdóticamente, el motivo de cierre indicado es **Demasiado amplia**. Sí, ya sé que solo quiere decir que *la mayoría* de los que votaron fue por ese motivo, pero me resulta curioso :-)

**EDITO**

Siguiendo recomendaciones surgidas en el *chat*, he editado la *susodicha* un poco. Por lo menos, aclarar qué juego es, sin tener que mirar todo el código.

Comment: Es una pregunta de la familia *muro de texto*. Vomito mi código y no explico nada... salvo en el título (que no es para explicar el problema si no para explicar la pregunta) y los comentarios (que si algo es relevante para la pregunta debería estar en la pregunta, no en los comentarios)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Si, efectivamente. Es una pregunta *muro de código*. Como tantas otras que hay por ahí; la primera que me viene a la cabeza: [Leer grandes archivos de texto de forma rapida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/63570/19610).

Comment: Después de hablarlo en el *chat*, estoy de acuerdo en que un mínimo de explicación hubiera sido deseable. He editado la pregunta en cuestión (3 líneas).

Comment: La pregunta en su texto original yo también la habría cerrado. Pero el motivo de cierre es como la pregunta, "No demuestra esfuerzo" (por elegir un motivo de cierre correcto).

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Yo catalogo la pregunta como del tipo `Depura mi Código`; como tal, si cumpliría lo [mínimo exigible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)(punto 1): el código (me remito a lo dicho sobre la capacidad del OP para *minimizarlo*), el comportamiento observado, el comportamiento esperado, y una descripción del problema (el propio título de la pregunta). Yo lo vi claro. Entiendo que otros no. Otras veces, ocurre al contrario :-)

Comment: @Trauma Con lo que no cumple la pregunta, en su edición original, es con "esta pregunta demuestra trabajo de investigación". Claro que eso es motivo para votar negativo, no para cerrar, así que te tengo que dar la razón.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estos son los puntos, casi retóricos, que expuse en el chat. Me parecieron que aplicaban bien a esta pregunta:

- En estos casos, siempre me pregunto: ¿si en vez de hacer toda una publicación en Meta, hubieses editado la pregunta para **agregar una descripción** de cuál era el problema? Ya que te tomaste el tiempo de leer la pregunta, entenderla y responderla, ¿no te conviene de paso **editar la pregunta** para que quede clara?
- Al menos una línea que diga "es un ta-te-tí (*3 en línea*), cuando no quedan más espacios disponibles debería salir pero no lo hace"... cualquier pregunta sin una m#%$#!/\ línea explicando va a ser mal recibida, se entienda o no.
- ¿Por qué quien lee la pregunta tiene que analizar el código hasta ver qué juego es, y cuál sería la condición de "empate"?

---

Luego se editó la pregunta agregando esta información, y creo que quedó mucho más aceptable.

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. eres extremadamente *puntilloso* en las ediciones de las preguntas XD. 2. Tienes razón en todos los puntos. A ver si *espabilo* para la próxima.

Comment: Jaja. Sólo fue para editar la etiqueta, y luego me dejé llevar por mi **[TOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC7it.jpg)**.

Comment: Mi principal punto... No hay el mínimo intento de debug. Como mínimo un printf antes de finalizar el bucle para ver los valores de `fin` y `contador`. Y entonces sí que se habría hecho una pregunta interesante ("porqué el valor de contador es siempre 0 si lo voy incrementando", supongo)